# Is the property of the mean being equal to the variance unique to the Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

Just asking out of curiosity. A homework question asked for the mean and variance of a distribution, and they turned out to be equal. It's not obvious to me that the distribution in question is poisson though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no

take a normal with mean and variance 1. I.e. a standard normal plus 1.

Comment: Oh true, didn't think about it like that. But to take it one step further, is Poisson the only one where you do not have to specify the parameter?

Comment: I don't the question is really mathematically answerable -- you could always define a sub-class of a more general family which restricts it to cases where mean and variance are equal.